# google captcha nocaptcha in html form

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I am trying to figure out how to add the new google recaptcha to my form. I have followed all the steps and documentation but the verification fails. Please help with adding the correct lines to my php file.

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter your name.</div>';
exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
exit();
} else if(trim($comments) == '') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter your message.</div>';
exit();
} 


if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$comments = stripslashes($comments);
}


// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

//$address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";
$address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";


// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

$e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';


// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name with regards to $subject, their additional message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email or via phone $phone";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

// Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

echo "<fieldset>";
echo "<div id='success_page'>";
echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the complete code, I don't see where you verify the response. You have to make an API Call to `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify` and verify whether the user id valid. You can read more about it here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't added the google code yet. I don't know where it should be added. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: check this tutorial : http://www.9lessons.info/2014/12/google-new-recaptcha-using-php-are-you.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, I checked these tutorials but i am stuck at the part where you have to add the captcha codes. I don't know where to add the codes to fit with what I already have. I'm can work with html but I'm a newbie to php and since I have a different code in my contact.php file, I don't know where to add the google recaptcha code lines.

Comment: Post your complete code

Comment: That's the complete code. It's a basic contact form that I have. The only thing missing there is the code for the recaptcha which I don't know where to add. I would very much appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you should have just wrote an HTML file and put `<?php ?>` in it to write the necessary PHP code and everything else, in HTML. Google reCAPTCHA requires you to:

1. Use the `script` tag inside the `head` tag to include their JS code.
2. Use a `form` to put your reCAPTCHA in.
3. Submit a POST request to `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify` with 2 parameters - `secret` and `response`

And all of them need HTML. I suggest you to rebuild your form in HTML and use PHP when necessary, like verifying the email and stuff, but you *really* do need HTML.

Comment: It is very insecure to post both your public and private key to google in html. The captcha can be easily tampered with this way.